# Exceptions while starting Eureka

Tags: java, netflix-eureka

I was trying to initialize my Eureka server and then i got the following exception:

````
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1211) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:629) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getClass(ReflectionHelper.java:625) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.getParameterizedType(ContextResolverFactory.java:202) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.init(ContextResolverFactory.java:89) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1332) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4530) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.alura.microservice.eureka.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 65 common frames omitted

2022-06-16 15:55:09.544 ERROR 15368 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-06-16 15:55:09.544 ERROR 15368 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-06-16 15:55:09.549  WARN 15368 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [spring.cloud.inetutils] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3463)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3434)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2022-06-16 15:55:09.631  INFO 15368 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-16 15:55:09.633  WARN 15368 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted```
````

So i search for the solution and found that i needed to add the following depencies, so i did it:

````
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>```
````

tryed this one too:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And then the old exception got replaced by a new one:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:989) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:592) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:514) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:483) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:429) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:396) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.XmlXStream.<init>(XmlXStream.java:51) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.XmlXStream.<clinit>(XmlXStream.java:42) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers$XStreamXml.<init>(CodecWrappers.java:358) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.create(CodecWrappers.java:133) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.getEncoder(CodecWrappers.java:75) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.getEncoder(CodecWrappers.java:66) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.<init>(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.<init>(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:64) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:180) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:159) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:153) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:278) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProviders(ProviderServices.java:151) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:175) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1338) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) ~[jersey-core-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790) ~[jersey-server-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744) ~[jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4530) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.alura.microservice.eureka.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @3646a422
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:40) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50) ~[xstream-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    ... 83 common frames omitted

2022-06-16 16:18:06.335 ERROR 6268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-06-16 16:18:06.336 ERROR 6268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-06-16 16:18:06.341  WARN 6268 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [spring.cloud.inetutils] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3463)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3434)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2022-06-16 16:18:06.424  INFO 6268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-16 16:18:06.426  WARN 6268 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-06-16 16:18:06.444  INFO 6268 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-16 16:18:06.447 ERROR 6268 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.alura.microservice.eureka.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:171) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:109) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

So im stuck on this until now.. im using the right versions (java 8), tryed to download the instructor complete project and still having the same error. Just dont know what to do.

[Here is the full project](https://caelum-online-public.s3.amazonaws.com/1233-spring-cloud-microservices/01/microsservicos-workspace-aula-1.zip) in case someone want to try